# SQL Grouping by part of string & return comma-separated

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm trying to group on the data within a string like 'Item-%'. Problem is this can be anywhere in the string. Further to complicate, I need to then return comma-separated list only containing the same item-% text.

Here is how data looks:

DocketQuestionsAndAnswers

[image]

I want to return data looking like:

[image]

My code so far is:

```
SELECT 
    JobNumber, 
    substring(Answer, patindex('Item%', answer) - 1, 7), 
    Notes = 
       STUFF((SELECT ', ' + rtrim(Answer)
              FROM DocketQuestionsAndAnswers b 
              WHERE b.JobNumber = a.JobNumber
                AND Screen like '%cut%'
                AND Answer like '%item%'
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM 
    DocketQuestionsAndAnswers a
WHERE 
    JOBNUMBER IN (SELECT JobNumber
                  FROM /* Query to filter job number */)
GROUP BY 
    JobNumber, 
    substring(Answer, patindex('Item%', answer) - 1, 7)
HAVING 
    substring(Answer, patindex('Item%', answer) - 1, 7) like '%item-%'
```

And this gets me only to this data:

[image]

How do I get only the comma separated values for each item? My example contains only 1 job number, but I need it for many based on my subquery. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't adding an additional condition for your STUFF subquery for Answer get you the result?

```
SELECT 
JobNumber, 
substring(Answer, patindex('%Item%', answer), 7), 
Notes = 
   STUFF((SELECT ', ' + rtrim(Answer)
          FROM DocketQuestionsAndAnswers b 
          WHERE b.JobNumber = a.JobNumber
            AND substring(a.Answer, patindex('%Item%', a.answer), 7) = 
               substring(b.Answer, patindex('%Item%', b.answer) , 7)
            AND Screen like '%cut%'
            AND Answer like '%item%'
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM 
DocketQuestionsAndAnswers a
WHERE 
JOBNUMBER IN (SELECT JobNumber
              FROM /* Query to filter job number */)
GROUP BY 
JobNumber, 
substring(Answer, patindex('%Item%', answer), 7)   --All patindexes changed from 'Item%'
HAVING 
substring(Answer, patindex('%Item%', answer), 7) like '%item-%'
```

Comment: Sounds logical, but throws error, `Column 'DocketQuestionsAndAnswers.Answer' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: OOps missed that bit. Fixed now

Comment: Much closer, only now its ignoring answer fields that have item-% not at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Oh, I found it.  It was my patindex.  The pattern should be `'%Item%'` to get what I want.

Comment: Is the query right? It would still give you 3 rows right?

Comment: You didn't need the PatIndex - 1 . Heres the SQLFiddle - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a5276/17

Comment: @TMNT- Yea, I found that I didn't need the -1.  I want 2 rows with data from all three as stated in the OP. Your answer, plus my patindex change did the trick.